# Superbad Mistake?

Tags: plot-explanation, superbad

In 'Superbad', Evan, Seth, and Fogell got kicked off the bus after a bottle of Goldslick broke and spilled on the floor.

But after they got kicked off the bus, they walked in the **opposite** direction that the bus was traveling.

Knowing that they got kicked off the bus before they arrived at their intended destination, shouldn't they have been walking in the **same** direction as the bus (in order to get to the party)?

Comment: Sometimes the closest stop to a destination is just past that destination. Would you stop two blocks before, or half a block after?  Clearly, you get off after if that's the case.

Comment: @AndrewMattson: True - But that would imply that they got kicked off *just* before the stop. Perhaps that's true, but they didn't seem like they were anticipating the stop when they got kicked off.

Comment: Good point, but another thing to keep in mind is that bus routes don't always follow a linear path.  Quite often they wind around in neighborhoods, so the direction the bus was pointed when they got kicked off might not be the same as it would be a few stops later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to slightly dispute Alenanno's answer; buses have cords that run above the windows.  A bus can stop at any intersection with enough notice, typically you tell the driver you need to stop and then pull the cord.

Therefore, if the party was actually passed by the bus, it's more logical that Evan, Seth and Fogell would have pulled the cord *before* the incident that caused them to get kicked off the bus.  By riding the bus past the party, they made extra work for themselves.

I think this was, in fact, a logic flaw, unless the bus' normal route would have circled around.

Think of it this way; let's say the party was on the corner of Manhattan Ave and 116th.  If the bus was supposed to go up Lenox Ave, take a left at MLK and then take another left onto Manhattan Ave, and they got kicked off at the corner of Lenox and 120th, it's *logical* they would have walked in the opposite direction the bus was travelling because it would have been a shorter walk.

[image]

Comment: Clearly they were distracted by losing their booze, so it could very well be that they intended to pull the cord after passing by the party - with the first after-stop being closer than the one before, but things got crazy before they got a chance to pull the cord.

Answer (score 7):

It's been a while since I've seen the movie but I think the reason is pretty simple: we don't really know where the house is located. We know it's really close, so close that the trio gets to reach it on foot after they get kicked off the bus, but I doubt the house is directly in front of it.

There are multiple reasons why this is likely not a mistake:

1. The bus rarely goes directly straight on to the place you're going to. It goes to bus stops that might be close to the point you want to go to, but it's not a given.
2. The bus needs to use not only the streets that might not go directly to that point, but also the streets it can use because of city conformation, streets with a single marching direction, etc. So, a smaller number of streets might be available to reach a certain point, causing you to take long turns or weird paths to get to a relatively easy and close point.
3. The place where the bus stopped in the movie is on the side of the house they want to go to and maybe slightly off. For all I (we) know, as stated in the reason 2, the bus could have taken a turn some distance after that unexpected stop and they would have gotten closer. The bus path is unknown to us viewers.

I think that speaking from the **point of view of a vehicle**, the bus was taking there sooner, not because it chose the most direct path, but because it's faster than a human on foot, and even taking turns and traffic lights it would get you there sooner.

**On foot** they take another route that is faster because you use paths that are unusable by vehicles: back alleys, stairs, parks, etc.